# Обход дерева каталогов и подсчёт общего числа файлов

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо прочитать дерево каталогов, начиная с указанного. Также требуется подсчитать общее количество обнаруженных файлов(исключая `.` и `..`). Результат выполнения функции нужно записать в отдельный файл. Фильтры поиска не требуются, т.к. все файлы одного типа. Мой вариант реализации:

```
static const char* filter = ".";
QStringList create_config(QString dir_name)
{
    QStringList ret_list;

    QDir dir(dir_name);

    QFileInfoList info_list = dir.entryInfoList();

    if(info_list.size() > 2)
    {
       QList<QFileInfo>::iterator iter=info_list.begin();

       QString path;

       for(iter=info_list.begin()+2;iter != info_list.end();iter++)
       {
           path = iter->absoluteFilePath();

           if(iter->isDir())
           {
               ret_list += create_config(path);
           }

           else
           {
               char ext[5];

               strncpy(ext,path.toStdString().c_str() + (path.size() - 4),5);

               if(!strcmp(ext, filter))ret_list.append(path);
           }
       }
      }
     return ret_list;

}
```

Comment: пишете код на qt+cpp и вставляете кусок на чистом си... `iter->completeSuffix() == filter` ну и конечно, `QString filter = "...";`

Comment: А что не работает? И зачем использовать `char` и `strncpy` в коде на Qt? Или всё, что связано с Qt Вы где-то скопировали, а ту часть, что после `else` уже сами писали?

Comment: Часть которая с C++  это из моего другого проекта, а то что на Qt  в Шлее подсмотрел.

Comment: А не работает запись в ret_list. Как я понимаю после прохода по каталогам в ret_list  попадают записи прочитанные в каталоге. Затем мне останется count-ом подсчитать число записей и все хорошо, но вот как избавиьтся от . и .. я вообще не понял.

Comment: но мне кажется я там сильно на говнокодил(((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Немного облагородил Ваш код современным C++:

```
QStringList create_config(const QString& dir_name)
{
    QStringList ret_list;
    QDir dir(dir_name);
    QFileInfoList info_list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllEntries);
    for(const auto& fileInfo : info_list)
    {
        auto path = fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();
        if(fileInfo.isDir())
            ret_list << create_config(path);
        else
            ret_list << path;

    }
    return ret_list;
}
```

Comment: Несмотря на `implicit sharing` не стоит ли передавать аргумент как `const QString&`? А `if/else` я бы в тернарный оператор превратил здесь.

Comment: @alexolut, стоит, исправил. Насчёт тернарного оператора: он выглядит стильно-молодёжно, но код от него, на мой взгляд, только пострадает.

Comment: `стильно-молодёжно` :-D Учитывая имеющуюся длинную строку с объявлением `info_list` тернарка будет, имхо, довольно элегантно вписываться: `ret_list << fileInfo.isDir() ? create_config(path) : path;`. Всё довольно прозрачно на мой взгляд. Хотя, возможно понадобятся скобки. Тогда это уже не айс.

Comment: @alexolut, я неоднократно слышал, что люди испытывают проблемы с чтением тернарного оператора, поэтому я стараюсь не использовать его тогда, когда он мало что даёт. Этот случай как раз такой: да будет короче, но if/else читается быстрее(вертикальное vs. горизонтальное чтение)

Answer (score 2):

Получение полного списка файлов посредством `QDir::entryInfoList()` может быть избыточным, если файлов в отдельных директориях окажется много и/или сама задача не предполагает дальнейшей работы со строками результата как с целостным набором данных.

В вопросе упоминается, что результат работы функции `create_config()` должен быть впоследствии записан в отдельный файл. В связи с этим обстоятельством использование `QDirIterator` может оказаться продуктивнее, нежели чем формирование единого (и наверняка не слишком маленького) списка имён файлов.

```
int create_config(const QString &src_path, const QString &dst_fname) {
    QFile file(dst_fname);
    if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly|QFile::Truncate|QFile::Text) == false)
        return -1;

    QTextStream stream(&file);

    int files_count = 0;

    QDirIterator itr(src_path
        , QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files
        , QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        itr.next();

        stream << itr.fileInfo().absoluteFilePath();

        ++files_count;        
    }

    return files_count;
}
```

Данный пример функции принимает в качестве аргументов путь, где требуется искать файлы, а также имя выходного файла, куда будет сохранён список с результатом. На выходе функция вернёт количество найденных файлов, либо "-1", если по какой-либо причине выходной файл не удалось создать/открыть.

Благодаря флагу `QDirIterator::Subdirectories` итератор переберёт каталоги рекурсивно, отчего организация рекурсии для собственной функции становится не нужна. В каждый момент времени в памяти будет находиться только одна строка с именем файла, что позволяет производить обход каталогов со сколь угодно большим количеством файлов, не снижая скорости.